# Left join com lambda GroupJoin e com condição

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, expressões-lambda

Como é que posso fazer um `left join` com algumas condições usando expressões LINQ lambda?

Em **SQL Server** tenho esta query:

```
select usr.Id, usr.FirstName, usr.LastName, ex.Id
from User usr
left join Exam ex on ex.Id = usr.IdExam 
and (ex.Id is null or (ex.InitialDate is null or ex.InitialDate >= getdate())
and (ex.EndDate is null or ex.EndDate <= getdate()))
```

Mas preciso fazê-la em **C#** e tentei fazer desta forma com o `GroupJoin`:

```
dataModel.User
    .GroupJoin(dataModel.Exam,
        usr => usr.IdExam, ex => ex.Id,
        (usr, ex) => new { Usr = usr, Ex= ex})
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .SelectMany(final => final.Exam.Where(ex => ex == null ||
                                ((!ex.InitialDate.HasValue || DateTime.Compare(ex.InitialDate.Value, DateTime.Now) <= 0)
                                && (!ex.EndDate.HasValue || DateTime.Compare(ex.EndDate.Value, DateTime.Now) >= 0))),
        (final, ex) => new
        {
           IdUser = final.Usr.Id,
           FirstName = final.Usr.FirstName,
           LastName = final.Usr.LastName,
           IdExam = ex.Id
        }).ToList();
```

O problema é que em C# a expressão está a retornar menos dados que a query em SQL. O que estou a fazer de errado?

Comment: Ninita, fiz uma pergunta abordando sua dúvida http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50456/entity-framework-left-join, nela demostro também minha forma de fazer left join

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: Troquei o lugar do where, a lógica que e fiz é pra a coleção já achatada, sinta-se a vontade de fazer outra.

O GroupJoin já faz um left join, a questão é que depois precisamos "achatar" com o selectmany, a sua query no leftjoin parece correta, mas o DefaultIfEmpty está no lugar errado.

```
dataModel.User
    .GroupJoin(dataModel.Exam,
        usr => usr.IdExam, ex => ex.Id,
        (usr, ex) => new { Usr = usr, Ex= ex.DefaultIfEmpty() })
```

Até aqui só o LeftJoin sem filtro e sem achatar.

```
dataModel.User
            .GroupJoin(dataModel.Exam,
                usr => usr.IdExam, ex => ex.Id,
                (usr, ex) => new { Usr = usr, Ex= ex.DefaultIfEmpty() })
            .SelectMany(final => final.Ex,
                        (final, ex) => new
                        {
                           IdUser = final.Usr.Id,
                           FirstName = final.Usr.FirstName,
                           LastName = final.Usr.LastName,
                           IdExam = ex != null ? ex.Id : 0
                        })
```

Após achatar, o filtro.

```
dataModel.User
        .GroupJoin(dataModel.Exam,
            usr => usr.IdExam, ex => ex.Id,
            (usr, ex) => new { Usr = usr, Ex= ex.DefaultIfEmpty() })
        .SelectMany(final => final.Ex,
                (final, ex) => new
                {
                   IdUser = final.Usr.Id,
                   FirstName = final.Usr.FirstName,
                   LastName = final.Usr.LastName,
                   // Uma forma de proteger do null, não testado.
                   IdExam = ex != null ? ex.Id : 0
                })          
        .Where(final => (final.Ex == null) ||
                        ((final.Ex.Id == null || final.Ex.InitialDate == null || final.Ex.InitialDate >= DateTime.Now) &&
                        (final.Ex.EndDate == null || final.Ex <= DateTime.Now)))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Fantástico! Já tinha visto muita gente fazer o `DefaultIfEmpty` depois do `GroupJoin` ou dentro do `SelectMany` mas nunca tinha encontrado esta abordagem. Com o seu código tive apenas que alterar a linha `IdExam = ex.Id` para `Ex = ex` senão não tinha acesso ao Ex no `Where` e obtinha uma exceção dizendo que não era possivel obter int de um null (e está correto). Agradeço-lhe muito pelo apoio, foi fantástico

Comment: o que seria `Achatar o filtro` ?

Comment: Faltou uma vírgula, vou arrumar. Sim Ninita, Ex pode ser null, vou colocar uma possível proteção. Fiz de cabeça esses detalhes passam.