# Entity Framework Left Join

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

Vendo a pergunta [Left join com lambda GroupJoin e com condição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50365/left-join-com-lambda-groupjoin-e-com-condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o), me surgiu duvidas em torno da forma como faço os `Left Join` com linq

Tendo as seguintes entidades

```
public class Cidade 
    {
        public int CidadeId { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public int EstadoId { get; set; }
    }

public class Estado
    {
        public int EstadoId { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public string Sigla { get; set; }
    }
```

a forma que sempre fiz meu left join

```
 var estados = from e in context.Estado
                              join c in context.Cidade on e.EstadoId equals c.EstadoId into cl
                              from c in cl.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              select e;
```

SQL gerado

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[EstadoId] AS [EstadoId], 
    [Extent1].[Descricao] AS [Descricao], 
    [Extent1].[Sigla] AS [Sigla], 
    [Extent1].[UsuarioCad] AS [UsuarioCad], 
    [Extent1].[DataHoraCad] AS [DataHoraCad], 
    [Extent1].[Ativo] AS [Ativo]
    FROM  [dbo].[Estado] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Cidade] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[EstadoId] = [Extent2].[EstadoId]
```

forma proposta nas respostas da dúvida [Left join com lambda GroupJoin e com condição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50365/left-join-com-lambda-groupjoin-e-com-condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

```
var dados2 = context.Estado
                    .GroupJoin(context.Cidade, e => e.EstadoId, c => c.EstadoId,
                            (estado, cidade) => new { E = estado, C = cidade.DefaultIfEmpty() })
                            .SelectMany(final => final.C, (final, ex) => new
                            {
                                EstadoId = final.E.EstadoId,
                                Descricao = final.E.Descricao,
                                Sigla = final.E.Sigla,
                                Cidade = ex.Descricao
                            }).ToList();
```

SQL gerado

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[EstadoId] AS [EstadoId], 
    [Extent1].[Descricao] AS [Descricao], 
    [Extent1].[Sigla] AS [Sigla], 
    [Extent2].[Descricao] AS [Descricao1]
    FROM  [dbo].[Estado] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Cidade] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[EstadoId] = [Extent2].[EstadoId]
```

Minha dúvida, o que seria melhor em termos de performance?

Na minha opinião, a forma como escrevo o `Left Join` é mais clara, confesso que na outra abordagem eu fico meio confuso.

Pelo que pude observar as intruções `SQL` são basicamente as mesmas

Comment: Também acho que com LINQ fica mais claro. Usando Lambda Expressions, expressões como os `Join` e os `GroupJoin`ficam um pouco confusas e o código torna-se muito extenso. O meu patrão acha que com Lambda as queries tornam-se mais rápidas mas eu também estou na dúvida. Umas vezes noto que é mais rápido com Lambda mas há queries em LINQ que são também rápidas. Depende da query que se faça

Comment: amigo, ambos são linq, o primeiro caso é "query expression" e o segundo "lambda expression". Internamente "query expression" são convertidas para "lambda expression", devido a isto "lambda" é um pouco mais rapido que "query", porém acredito que este pequeno ganho não compensa a perda de legibilidade, por fim você pode olhar o seguinte site para um comparativo: http://blog.thijssen.ch/2009/02/linq-vs-lambda-vs-loop-performance-test.html

Comment: Não há ganho ou perda significativa de performance considerando ambos os cenários, visto que LINQ ou então os métodos de expressão são apenas formas de se construir um comando que gera um SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Minha dúvida, o que seria melhor em termos de performance?

Ambas as sintaxes são iguais para o compilador que converte no mesmo código, sem ônus pois é compile time.

O código abaixo é o do post citado pelo TobyMosque, só que da forma certa. Vou discutir abaixo.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace IterationPerformanceTest
{
    class Program
    {
        const int SIZE = 10000;
        const int RUNS = 1000;

        static Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        static Random r = new Random();

        static List<int> intList = new List<int>();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                intList.Add(r.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue));

            RunLoop();            

            RunQuerySyntax();

            RunFluentSyntax();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void RunQuerySyntax()
        {
            stopwatch.Reset();

            //Query Syntax  
            stopwatch.Start();

            for (int t = 0; t < RUNS; ++t)
            {
                var result = (from int i in intList where i < 10 select i).ToList();
            }

            stopwatch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Query Syntax : {0}, avg. {1}", stopwatch.Elapsed, new TimeSpan(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks / RUNS)));
        }

        static void RunFluentSyntax()
        {
            stopwatch.Reset();

            //Fluent Syntax
            stopwatch.Start();

            for (int t = 0; t < RUNS; ++t)
            {
                var result = intList.Where(i => i < 10).ToList();
            }

            stopwatch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Fluent Syntax: {0}, avg. {1}", stopwatch.Elapsed, new TimeSpan(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks / RUNS)));   
        }

        static void RunLoop()
        {
            stopwatch.Reset();

            //LOOP  
            stopwatch.Start();

            for (int t = 0; t < RUNS; ++t)
            {
                var result = new List<int>();

                foreach (var i in intList)
                {
                    if (i < 10) result.Add(i);
                }
            }

            stopwatch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Loop: {0}, avg. {1}", stopwatch.Elapsed, new TimeSpan(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks / RUNS)));

        }
    }
}
```

Isolei as chamadas para ficar fácil no CIL de analisar e outro coisa...

Loop do Query Syntax:

```
// loop start (head: IL_004a)
        IL_0010: nop
        IL_0011: ldsfld class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32> IterationPerformanceTest.Program::intList
        IL_0016: call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0> [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::Cast<int32>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.IEnumerable)
        IL_001b: ldsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, bool> IterationPerformanceTest.Program::'CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1'
        IL_0020: brtrue.s IL_0035

        IL_0022: ldnull
        IL_0023: ldftn bool IterationPerformanceTest.Program::'<RunQuerySyntax>b__0'(int32)
        IL_0029: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, bool>::.ctor(object, native int)
        IL_002e: stsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, bool> IterationPerformanceTest.Program::'CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1'
        IL_0033: br.s IL_0035

        IL_0035: ldsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, bool> IterationPerformanceTest.Program::'CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1'
        IL_003a: call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0> [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::Where<int32>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>, class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<!!0, bool>)
        IL_003f: call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<!!0> [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::ToList<int32>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>)
        IL_0044: stloc.1
        IL_0045: nop
        IL_0046: ldloc.0
        IL_0047: ldc.i4.1
        IL_0048: add
        IL_0049: stloc.0

        IL_004a: ldloc.0
        IL_004b: ldc.i4 1000
        IL_0050: clt
        IL_0052: stloc.2
        IL_0053: ldloc.2
        IL_0054: brtrue.s IL_0010
    // end loop
```

Loop do Fluent Syntax

```
// loop start (head: IL_0045)
        IL_0010: nop
        IL_0011: ldsfld class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32> IterationPerformanceTest.Program::intList
        IL_0016: ldsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, bool> IterationPerformanceTest.Program::'CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate3'
        IL_001b: brtrue.s IL_0030

        IL_001d: ldnull
        IL_001e: ldftn bool IterationPerformanceTest.Program::'<RunFluentSyntax>b__2'(int32)
        IL_0024: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, bool>::.ctor(object, native int)
        IL_0029: stsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, bool> IterationPerformanceTest.Program::'CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate3'
        IL_002e: br.s IL_0030

        IL_0030: ldsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32, bool> IterationPerformanceTest.Program::'CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate3'
        IL_0035: call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0> [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::Where<int32>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>, class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<!!0, bool>)
        IL_003a: call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<!!0> [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::ToList<int32>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>)
        IL_003f: stloc.1
        IL_0040: nop
        IL_0041: ldloc.0
        IL_0042: ldc.i4.1
        IL_0043: add
        IL_0044: stloc.0

        IL_0045: ldloc.0
        IL_0046: ldc.i4 1000
        IL_004b: clt
        IL_004d: stloc.2
        IL_004e: ldloc.2
        IL_004f: brtrue.s IL_0010
    // end loop
```

Praticamente gêmeos!

Atente para o fato de o exemplo ter refatorado as chamadas em métodos isolados, experimente trocar a ordem do Fluent com o Query e dependendo do seu processador/carga o de baixo sempre irá ser ligeiramente mais rápido, isso não tem nada a ver com performance da query e sim cache hit, cada máquina irá ter um ganho diferente, visto que é sempre a mesma coleção a ser percorrida, se ela está no cache do processador é mais rápido.

Muito cuidado com os exemplos pela internet, esse citado continha vários erros de análise e técnica.