# Como realizar um Left Join com LINQ C# usando meu SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-sql

**Exemplo que funciona no SQL:**

```
select * from Doacoes
inner join Projetos on Projetos.IdProjeto = Doacoes.IdProjeto
left join Pedidos on Doacoes.IdDoacao = Pedidos.IdDoacao
left join Recompensas on Pedidos.IdRecompensa = Recompensas.IdRecompensa
where Doacoes.IdUsuario = 2017
```

**Realizei a reescrita desta forma, mas não funciona:**

```
from d in banco.Doacoes
join p in banco.Projetos on d.IdProjeto equals p.IdProjeto
join pedi in banco.Pedidos on d.IdDoacao equals pedi.IdDoacao into pedi
join recompensa in banco.Recompensas  on recompensa.IdRecompensa equals 
pedi.IdRecompensa into pedi
```

Comment: Se não me engano é a mesma coisa, `left join pedi in...`. 3 anos que não uso Linq mas acho que é isso msm!

Answer (score 0):

Para ter o *left join* no *Entity Framework* você terá que fazer o seguinte

```
from d in banco.Doacoes
join p in banco.Projetos on d.IdProjeto equals p.IdProjeto
join pedi in banco.Pedidos on d.IdDoacao equals pedi.IdDoacao into pediLeft
from pedi in pediLeft.DefaultIfEmpety()
join recompensa in banco.Recompensas on recompensa.IdRecompensa equals pedi.IdRecompensa into recoLeft
from recompensa in recoLeft.DefaultIfEmpety()
```

De uma olhadinha nessa pergunta [Entity Framework Left Join](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50456/5846) também.